# Can't click() in a element on Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have a form That is clickable by mouse but can't with Selenium.
I find the Element but can't click.

Error is:

> Message: Element < tr class="ui-widget-content"> could not be scrolled into view"

And the HTML is:

```
<tr data-ri="1" data-rk="86358" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd ui-datatable-selectable" role="row" aria-selected="false">
    < td role="gridcell" style="width:15%;">20130200045442< /td>
    < td role="gridcell" style="width:15%;">00034509320104036138< /td>
    < td role="gridcell" style="text-align:left;width:35%">TEXTO< /td>
    < td role="gridcell" style="width:15%;">13/02/2012</td>
    < td role="gridcell" style="width:15%;">SERVIÇO PRESTADO< /td>
< /tr>
```

Comment: when the driver processes the click it will attempt to scroll it into view first.  This seems to be failing for some reason.  Can you post the full markup for this page?

Comment: I will change the values in the grid because of sensible information and post the complete <tbody> @pcalkins